# Extract data from an JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a data with `bs4` and `requests`, but when I scraping the elements, there is no text inside. So I recognize that the data is coming from an outside script.

The JavaScript script (event listener) is always will be next to the element ?

```
<span id='data'>523532</span> [event] (clickable to see the script link)
```

I can't see the text of the `span` element when scraping the website

Link: https://static.fcdn.co.il/dyn/projects/profileimageheader/profileimageheader.js?v1.7=4120.516

How can I get that data with `requests` and `bs4` ?

Comment: Could you please improve your question and provide the URL of the website, as well as a short description of the data you are trying to scrape? Also, any code of the attempts you made would be useful.

Comment: @Gregor The website blocks any IP that not from my country (I'm not from Germany). I'm trying to scrape data that comes from a JavaScript event, I can't just scrape it normally because I don't get anything from the element. I didn't try anything yet.